# Convert each column in dataframe to separate dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

Say I have a dataframe with 10 columns where each of the 10 columns represents a separate timeseries.

I'd like to store each timeseries(or each column of the dataframe) in a separate dataframe.

I have tried using assign("columnname", df[,i]) where i is a variable in a for loop running from 1 to number of columns. This results in character vectors of each column, where I require dataframes instead.

Any idea how I might proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Create a test dataframe
df <- data.frame(c(1:3), c(3:5), c(8:10))
colnames(df) <- c("col1","col2","col3")

#### VERSION 1 ####
# Creates a new dataframe from each column, but lose the original column names in the new dataframes
for(i in 1:ncol(df))
  {assign(colnames(df)[i], data.frame(df[,i]))}

#### VERSION 2 ####
# Creates a new dataframe from each column, maintains the original column names in the new dataframes
for(i in 1:ncol(df))
{temp <- data.frame(df[,i])
 colnames(temp) <- colnames(df)[i]
 assign(colnames(df)[i], temp)
 rm(temp)
}
```

Comment: Alternately, if the OP is willing to forgo `assign` (which is pretty much universally discouraged), there's `split.default(df, seq_along(df))` or `split.default(df, names(df))`

Comment: split.default is definitely a great alternative. Just keep in mind when you assign the split to a new object `x <- split.default(df, names(df))` that the resulting dataframes will be stored inside a list in that object and can then be referenced by their index in the list ie: using the index number of the dataframe `x[2]` or by using the name of the dataframe `x["col2"]`

Comment: Actually `x[["col2"]]`, right? `x["col2"]` will be a subset of the list, not an element of it.

Comment: Good catch @Frank, you're right it would be `x[["col2"]]` for the dataframe object