# extracting columns to separate dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to do something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43907992/convert-each-column-in-dataframe-to-separate-dataframe), but slightly different.

I have a dataframe with 33 columns. I need to have a series of dataframes that have the first column and one of the following columns each.

How can I do that?

**UPDATE**

Getting inspiration one of the answers in the question linked above, I tried to do the following:

```
for (i in 2:ncol(data))
{temp <- data.frame(data$col1, data[,i])
 colnames(temp) <- colnames(data)[i]
 assign(colnames(data)[i], temp)    
 rm(temp)
}
```

which works, but the labels of the two columns is mixed up, namely the first column get label, but not the second one.

Answer (score 2):

You can just put them in a list:

```
mylist <- list()

for(i in 1:32){
  mylist[[i]] <- df[,c(1, i+1)]
  names(mylist)[i] <- colnames(df)[i+1]
}
```

This will create a list of 32 dataframes, each with the first column and consecutively one of the others, starting with the second.

Comment: Thanks, but will I be able to run further analysis as if it was a dataframe?

Comment: Yes, you can access each 2-column data frame with `mylist[[i]]`, which will return the data frame itself

Comment: As @ChiPak said, the objects within the list are still of the class `data.frame`.

Comment: Sorry I miss that part (lol). Anyway, the cool thing about the code I put in the question is that it automatically names each dataframe as I want. I'd just need to assign the right colnames to the two columns.

Comment: I've included a line that names every dataframe by the colname of the variable column included. Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can do it with a function like:

```
makedf <- function(df, i) {
  df %>%
    select(c(1,i)) %>% 
    return()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Done.

```html
for (i in 2:ncol(data))
{temp <- data.frame(data[,1], data[,i])
 colnames(temp) <- c("col1", colnames(data)[i])
 assign(colnames(data)[i], temp) 
 rm(temp)
}
```

Comment: Well, you could do it like this, but one list including all dataframes will be much more efficient than cluttering your global environment with 32 dataframes. The list also allows you to simply loop further calculations over all subsets.

Comment: So do you think your solution is easier even if I have to then split the vectors of each of the dataframes and run separate analysis?

Comment: You can just use `lapply()` to loop your analyses over the list. What do you mean by splitting the vectors?

Comment: I have now 32 data frames having a long list of time series each. In each data frame, the first column identifies the latency, the second one the actual values. However, this long list reports different values for the same latencies. So, what I need to is to split the second column so that I have one latency column for all the actual values. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ah, I see. You can achieve that with `split(df, df[, 1])`. And you can use `lapply(mylist, function(x) split(x, x[, 1]))` to do this with all 32 data frames at once when they are in the list I provided in my answer ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151591/discussion-between-robertp-and-lap).