# How do I manipulate new columns in R after splitting a column with delimiter?

Tags: r, tidyr, csv

Hi I am an Excel User and work with a lot of Digital marketing data.

In Excel we have a function 'Text to column', where a column is split by a given delimiter.

I have an example template or format of a placement name which consists of a brief description of the campaign, product and other details: **ProductType_CreativeType_AdSize_Strategy_CreativeName_ProductName_Description**.

Now, I have to prepare a vlookup sheet where the **'strategy'** is extracted from the placement name and placed as a separate column beside the corresponding placement name.

[An example of how the reference sheet should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzVNw.png)

We use this reference sheet to fill a strategy column in another dataset.

I was trying to automate this task in R **(Please bear with me I am still learning R)**  and was successful in splitting the column by the delimiter.

However, I am trying to select the resultant split columns and save it as a new dataset/dataframe, but the new columns are being saved as a character vector and I am not able to save it as a dataset.

Here is the code I tried:

```
df<-df %>% separate(Placement, c("A", "B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","Placement"), sep = "_")
```

After splitting I would like to save column J to a new dataset, however it is saving as character vector and not as a dataset. Here is the code.

```
df2<-df$L
```

I have also tried the select function

```
df2<-select(df$L)
```

It is giving me the following error.

> Error in UseMethod("select_") : 
>     no applicable method for 'select_' applied to an object of class "character"

How do I select the split columns and save them as a dataset, as I have to do further processing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `df2 <- as.data.frame(df$L)`............I'm presuming the fact you said you would like to save column J, but referenced column L then was a typo

Comment: Sorry for the miss, Yes any column would work.

Comment: Thanks NColl it actually worked. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi I just checked and I see I have to select multiple columns and save it as a dataset, could you tell me how that could be possible?

Comment: when I get that error I need to type `dplyr::select(df$L)` and that fixes it sometimes

Answer (score 0):

Split data frame into multiple based off columns in original using a for loop. 
If you aren't sure which you need originally, based off this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43907992/convert-each-column-in-dataframe-to-separate-dataframe) it will split each of your dataframe columns into separate dataframes, you can then remove what you don't need

```
for(i in 1:ncol(df)) {
  temp <- data.frame(df[,i])
  colnames(temp) <- colnames(df)[i]
  assign(colnames(df)[i], temp)
  rm(temp)
}
```